# how to insert the value of current primary key of parent table into child table

Tags: php, html, mysql

i have two table employee table(parent table) and employee_image table(child table).

### employee table (employee_id is auto increment primary key in this parent table)

```
|=============================|
|employee_id    employee_name |
|  1             ram          |
|  2             sham         |
|  3             dany         |
|  4             james        |
|=============================|
```

### employee_image table (after inserting values table should look like something this)

```
|=====================================================|
|image_id      name       image           employee_id |
|  1           img_one   [BLOB-22.3KiB]     2         |
|  2           img_two   [BLOB-24.5KiB]     3         |
|  3           img_three [BLOB-32.2KiB]     3         |
|  4           img_four  [BLOB-18.6KiB]     3         |
|  5           img_five  [BLOB-17.7KiB]     4         |
|=====================================================|
```

On first insert.php form  i am using this script

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="commit.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table>
<tr><td>employee name : </td><td><input type ="text" name ="employee_name"/></td></tr>
<tr><td>upload image 1 : </td><td><input type="file" name="image"></td></tr>
<tr><td>upload image 2 : </td><td><input type="file" name="image"></td></tr>
<tr><td>upload image 3 : </td><td><input type="file" name="image"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type ="submit" name="submit" value ="submit"/></td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

and in second page "commit.php" i am using this script

```
<?php
$db=mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or 
die ('Unable to connect. Check your connection paramerters.');

mysql_select_db('my_db', $db) or die(mysql_error($db));


$query ='INSERT INTO employee_tbl
(employee_name)
VALUES
("' . $_POST['employee_name'] . '")';
mysql_query($query, $db) or die(mysql_error($db));
echo 'employee name inserted succecfully!';

$imageName=mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
$imageData=mysql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]));
$imageType=mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES["image"]["type"]);

if(substr($imageType,0,5) == "image") 
{
mysql_query("insert into test_image values ('', '$imageName', '$imageData')");
echo "image uploaded";
}
else
{
 echo "only images are allowed";
}
}
?>
```

### Here employee_id is primary key in employee table (parent table). I want to insert one or two or three images simultaneously. My aim is to insert the current inserting employee_id in employee_image table (child table) also... how can i do this?  Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Don't save images as BLOBs in the db, you should store the img path.

Comment: Don't use `mysql_*` statments because they're DEPRECATED, and I don't see your $employee_id var in your code.

Comment: @NickR: There are pros and cons. Simply don't advise not to save as BLOBs.

Comment: Yes Mr. Foobar, i am not using $employee_id var in code because i don't know how to use it here to get employee_id i am beginner and i have to use blob to store images. thank you sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this

```
mysql_query("insert into test_image values ('', '$imageName', '$imageData')");
```

With:

```
$id = mysql_insert_id();
mysql_query("insert into test_image values ('', '$imageName', '$imageData','$id')");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the last inserted auto increment PK value by two ways -

1. by using MySQL command `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` [Reference:](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)
2. by using PHP `mysqli_insert_id()` function Reference:

For the method **1.**, you can use `SELECT last_insert_id()` in MySQL and the query will return the last inserted ID

For the method **2.** you can use `mysqli_insert_id()` function

Here is the example of method **2.** ***`mysqli_*` functions are used in the following example ***

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "my_db") 
or die(mysqli_error());

$query ='INSERT INTO employee_tbl
(employee_name)
VALUES
("' . $_POST['employee_name'] . '")';

mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error());
echo 'employee name inserted succecfully!';

$imageName=mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
$imageData=mysqli_real_escape_string($link, file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]));
$imageType=mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_FILES["image"]["type"]);

if(substr($imageType,0,5) == "image") 
{
    $id = mysqli_insert_id($link);
    mysqli_query($link, "insert into test_image values ('', '$imageName', '$imageData', '$id')");
    echo "image uploaded";
}
else
{
    echo "only images are allowed";
}
```

Comment: It is showing error   "Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\wamp\www..............on line......"

Comment: @vick ... sorry for that ... now the answer is updated! `mysqli_real_escape_string` needs two parameters ... in the example `$link` can be provided as first parameter ...